# How to track every reasonable click in android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, touch-event

I need to track an event each time user clicks on any clickable view in my app. I want to do this generally so e.g. in my main activity.
I know I can override `onUserInteraction()` or `dispatchTouchEvent()` but these are running even for the clicks which are not clickable views.

I don't need to differ between clickable views, just the fact it is clickable is enough.
In an ideal case, I would also differentiate the Up button from other clicks.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there's no flawless implementation for what you want to achieve.

One possible way is using a OnClickListener wrapper. This needs you or your team to enforce using this wrapper on any clickable views' OnClickListener. But you cannot cover the views in third party library.

```java
public class OnClickListenerWrapper implements OnClickListener {
    private OnClickListener listener
    public OnClickListenerWrapper (OnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Logic of tracking
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Track any click occurring on any clickable `View` in the app.

### Possible solution

This solution is a bit heavy and requires certain discipline from your side (do not use `setOnClickListener()` for other purposes but tracking clicks).

Add a `View.OnClickListener` to any `View` in your base `Activity` or any `Activity`, for which you would like to track down click events. Start doing this only when the global layout has finished loading (by adding an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`) to the root view. So, the code look could look as follows:

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();    
    decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() ->
        printClickedViews(getWindow().getDecorView())
    );
}

private void printClickedViews(View currentView) {
    if (currentView == null) {
        return;
    }

    currentView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked on " + v.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });

    if (currentView instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) currentView;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            printClickedViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
...
```

Please note that even if you add/remove a new `View`, your `OnGlobalLayoutListener` will get notified, and that's good.

### Limitations

**The most obvious limitation is that setting a `View.OnClickListener` will have to be reserved for tracking clicks only**. However, you can always use `OnTouchListener` for the same purpose as follows:

```
    view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // handle your click event here
        }
        
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To track all the clickable view use this approach :

1. Create an interface for click events

   ```
    package com.gethello.interfaces;

    import android.view.View;

    public interface OnItemClickInterfaceTesting {

       void onItemClick(View view,int id);


    }
   ```
2. Create a method in Base activity so that you can access in every activity .

```html
public void setClickListener(Context context, View view, int id) {

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Track your click events here");
                OnItemClickInterfaceTesting itemController = (OnItemClickInterfaceTesting) context;
                itemController.onItemClick(view, id);

            }
        });
    }
```

3. Implement OnItemClickInterfaceTesting and methods of interface in your activity.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(View view, int id) {
    switch (id){

        case R.id.id_of_your_view:
            Log.e(TAG, "Your view clicked. Add your code to handle click of view.");
            break;

    }
   }
   ```
4. Call method in onCreate like this :

   setClickListener(this,ViewName,R.id.id_of_view);
   [image: for example]

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for OOP.

1. Create a class that extends Button. In this class override the onClick listener and do whatever you need to do there. This SO seems helpful [Creating custom control with overriding onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808162/creating-custom-control-with-overriding-onclick)
2. Replace all  in layouts.xml with <your.package.custombutton>.

Repeat for other types of controls.

In general, it's not a bad idea to create Base Classes for all elements you will be using, as things like this come up all the time.